# Open source, how can I view "Transaction Create a new transaction" and "Sign Transaction"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, raw-transaction, createrawtransaction, signrawtransaction

Not long ago I saw on the site github.com the very first Nakamoto code:

https://github.com/livegnik/BitCoin-v0.01-ALPHA

Running `bitcoin.exe`, I did not find the console. If the program is open source, how can I view "Transaction Create a new transaction" and "Sign Transaction"?

I know that the program is written in C++
I would love to see the "Transaction" processes as on https://coinb.in
Coinbin source code is written in javascript. Can I view in C++?

Answer (score 1):

The original Bitcoin client did not have a debug console or many things that we see in modern Bitcoin software. Furthermore, it is a compiled software (C++ needs to be compiled) so you can't inspect the thing being run for its source code. However, Satoshi did publish the source code along with the pre-compiled binary. For transaction creation, you can find this in the repo you linked in `src/main.cpp`. It is the function named `CreateTransaction`. Another copy of the original distribution can be found on [nakamotoinstitute.org](https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/code/).

Lastly, Bitcoin Core is based on the original client's codebase. It's commit history goes all the way back to [0.1.5](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/v0.1.5) so you can see code that is very similar to the original release and view the code for any version between 0.1.5 and modern Bitcoin Core.